# how to reset plt.ylabel = '' back to its proper function

Tags: python, function, matplotlib

I accidentally set `plt.ylabel = 'blank string'`

Now when i try `plt.ylabel('')`, i get the error :

> TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Is there a function to reset these assignments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just re-import matplotlib again, so that `plt.ylabel` points to the method exported from `matplotlib.pyplot` and not the character string (`str`) with the value 'blank string'.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.ylabel("Label Text!")
```

[image]
If you're comfortable with importing just the `matplotlib.pyplot.ylabel` method instead of re-importing matplotlib, that can work too.

Additional reference is the [source code for `matplotlib.pyplot.ylabel`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/_modules/matplotlib/pyplot.html#ylabel) or the [official documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.ylabel.html).